# Stuck in mapping double value using FEMMAPPING with Coredata in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mapping

I am using femmapping in swift.I need guidance for mapping double value .My code is as bellow.

//For Product Class

```
let atr = FEMAttribute(property: property, keyPath: keyPath, map: { value -> Any? in
    if let value = value as? String, let convertedValue = Double(value) {
        return NSNumber(value: convertedValue)
    }
    return nil
}, reverseMap: { value -> Any? in
    if let value = value as? NSNumber {
        return value.stringValue
    }
    return nil
})
return atr 

// For Customer class 
let atr = FEMAttribute.init(property: property, keyPath: keyPath, map: { (valueInt) -> Double? in
    if(type(of: valueInt) == String.Type.self){
        return NSNumber.init(value: Double(valueInt as? String ?? "0.00") ?? 0.00000) as? Double
    }
    return valueInt as? Double
}, reverseMap: { (valueInt) -> Any? in
    return String(format: "%.02f", arguments: [Double(valueInt as? String ?? "0.00") ?? 0.00000])
})
return atr
```

if i am kepping first portion in second class functionality stopped working , same way if I am using second portion in first class functionality stopped working.
Can anyone help me out ??

Answer (score 0):

Actually from api response type was coming string for once class , So I change the data type from double to string and its worked.

Thanks Everyone